# Overhead of empty elastic search indices on performance

Tags: elasticsearch

We use Elastic search for full text search use cases. The data is metadata collected across different objects and stored as ES document. We also update the document in ES whenever the master data gets updated. So, basically it is not a logging use case.

We create one ES index (one primary and 1 replica shard) as soon as we have a tenant who gets onboard for our application. This is to ensure that the ES index is ready when the first object gets created.

We do not anticipate volume of data in the index. The data could range between few hundred of MBs per index. So this is a relatively empty index.

Also, full text search is an optional add-in feature in application, so not all tenants may opt for the same, however our technical team suggested creating index upfront.

What is the overhead of such indices on the ES performance? Are we doing anything different from best practices of ES?

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty Elasticsearch index don't have much overhead, as there is actually no data in them, only places where empty indices data is present in the cluster state(index mapping, setting etc) which every node in the cluster has and any change in the index mapping or settings ie index metadata updates the cluster state and gets updated on all the nodes in ES cluster.

If you have sufficient memory and ES heap size, you don't have to worry at all about these empty indices which IMO makes sense considering your use-case.

Comment: it's also worth noting that each index/shards has underlying segment files and the nodes which hosts the shards of that index need to keep a file handle on those segments and there's a maximum number of file handles available. So having too many indices, even if empty, can make you run out of file handles, so this needs to be monitored as well. `GET _nodes/stats?filter_path=**.*file_descriptors` will get you those metrics.

Comment: @Val thanks for the valuable comment, just one doubt, when index doesn't have any document than why segment would be created ?

Comment: I doubt that the index stays empty for a long time after the onboarding, otherwise why would the user onboard in the first place? By "relatively empty index" I assume the OP means "index with potentially very few documents in it"

Comment: Thank you for the answer and an informative thread here in the comments. It is true that most of the indices have documents that have storage in few MBs or even lesser (relatively empty), however, there are few hundreds of indices with no documents (completely empty), where the customer did not buy for the search feature. Is there a downside to this approach?

Comment: @tyrion, as explained earlier empty indices with no documents will take space only in cluster state which is OK if its in few MB and you don't get timeout while updating the cluster state in your cluster logs.